# Apex email extension points - How to replace Messaging.sendEmail or change it's behaviour

Tags: apex, email

I'm looking to alter the mechanism that SalesForce uses to send email.

Ideally I would like to make this change in a single location.

I could make a new class called CustomMailer that has the same interface as the system classes, and then replace all calls to

```
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
```

This would be quite a mammoth task in my org.

What would be preferable would be to somehow tell SalesForce - "Any calls that you receive to":

```
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
```

"Redirect to" ***CustomMailer.Send()***

i.e. Swap out the default implementation.

I suspect that providers of 3rd party email solutions for SalesForce already do this - the question is how?

Answer (score 2):

If I create a class called "Test" in my org, it overrides the standard Test class and all tests stop working. This suggests that you could create your own class called "Messaging" that would override the existing Messaging class.

But it would override it completely, including the SingleEmailMessage etc, so you'd have to implement the entirety of building and sending emails. It wouldn't allow you to intercept the send request, do some processing, and then carry on with the send request.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, that's a very interesting finding... I'll try it out with the actual messaging object in a developer org. If it behaves the same as your experiment I'll accept this as the answer. I am actually trying to completely replace messaging (I think...) so this might be just the right thing.